# "Could not find a required file" on `yarn start`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tree, yarnpkg

I set up a `create-react-app` and I'm trying to run App.js on localhost, but upon doing `yarn start` I get the following error message:

```
22:23 $ yarn start
yarn run v1.3.2
$ react-scripts start
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: /Users/-----/Desktop/---/----/hw/HW-REPO/hw-name/public
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I'd already installed yarn with `yarn install`, so I'm not sure if there's something wrong with my code or with the file structure.

Here's the file structure:

```
app-name
 -client
   --public
     ---index.html
     ---manifest.json
   --src
     ---Components
        ----various folders
     ---App.js
     ---App.test.js
     ---index.js
 -database
 -model
 -gitignore
 -package-lock.json
 -package.json
 -server.js
 -yarn.lock
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: I moved `yarn.lock and package.json` into the `client` folder, did `yarn install` again, and then ran `yarn start.` Now I'm seeing good ol' error messages in the browser. I'm not 100% sure if shuffling the files around did the trick or if it was doing `yarn install` *again,* but at least it's working now.

Comment: Not sure how you managed to make this work. From which folder did you run the install ?

Answer (score 8):

In my case command `npm audit fix --force` change version of react-scripts in package.json As I created app with --template typescript, older version of react-scripts could not find index.js, but I have index.tsx

I solve this by removing package-lock.json, node-modules folder and remove react-scripts from package.json, then `npm i react-scripts`

Answer (score 4):

In my case I opened my wrong folder in vs code and was trying to run npm start from their and npm did not find the index.html in that path, so I looked the correct path and reopened the folder and got no issue. Hope this will help some new beginner.

Answer (score 3):

@Tsardines I was experiencing the same issue, but the 'Could not find a required file' my program was referencing was 'index.js'.

```sh
$ yarn start
# yarn run v1.13.0
# warning ..\..\..\..\package.json: No license field
$ react-scripts start
# Could not find a required file.
# Name: index.js`
```

This was because my index.js file was in the root folder of my project, instead of being
in the 'src' folder.

I moved the file to src folder, ran 'yarn start'.
Presto!

Comment: If the file (index.js instead of index.html) was not the same then IMO you were not "facing the same issue". So it seems to me that your answer belongs to a different question